# ReactJS Framer-Motion scaling a div dynamically with AnimatePresence layout

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have a question regarding framer motion's AnimatePresence exit animations, and layout. I am rendering a list of components like this:

```
<div style={{ height: 'fit-content', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
 <AnimatePresence mode={'wait'}>
  items.map((id) => {
   return (<motion.div
    key={-id}
    layout
    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ layout: { type: 'spring' }}>

    <Item key={id}/>
   </motion.div>)
  })
 </AnimatePresence>
</div>
```

*(the code is just an example of what's going on going on, it might not do anything and it might have errors)*

Basically, the elements in the list collapse nicely when they are removed from the DOM. However, the outside div (which is fit-content) just snaps into place after the element is actually removed from the DOM. Ideally, I would like the outside div to interpolate its height to fit the new content (using framer motion or some funky ReactJS or CSS code).

Here's a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animatepresence-poplayout-mode-forked-jhmkqt?file=/src/App.tsx

*if you need any clarification please ask. thank you for taking the time to read this!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I managed to figure it out after a little more docs reading: https://www.framer.com/docs/layout-animations/. If you want a div to interpolate it's scale after a child re-renders, just add the word layout as a prop to the parent motion.div

In the code above it would look something like this:

```
<motion.div style={{ height: 'fit-content', backgroundColor: 'black' }} layout>
```